# getPendingNotificationRequests count is not decreasing on notification firing if UNCalendarNotificationTrigger repeat set to true

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a app in that i need to schedule more than 64 notification at a time so i am schedule 64 notifications first and storing rest in database.
All notification is scheduling with UNCalendarNotificationTrigger repeat "true", because that will repeat every day/week.

So problem is that count of pendingNotificationRequest doesn't decrease of notification fires.
if i schedule 60 notifications and 10 notification fires at scheduled time, still i get 60 pending notification request from below code.

if i set to trigger repeat false it works fine, Please assist how can it work in repeat true.

```
  let center1 = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center1.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { requests in
            print("Total Count : \(requests.count)")
        })
```

Comment: Why would you expect the number to decrease?  If you have repeating notifications then they are still pending.  The short answer is it can't work if you have repeat true. You will need to manage your own repetition.

Comment: Like i have 200 local notification in queue (in database) and scheduled first 64 local notifications when these first will be fired i have to schedule next 64 from the queue, So how would i know the first 64 has been fired?

Comment: You have to check when your app is launched/becomes active.  You can also schedule a background refresh task https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgapprefreshtaskrequest to periodically check which notifications have been fired and to schedule the next 64.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Paulw11, but my question is how can i check the fired notifications and how many has been fired.